# git: how to move a branch's root two commits back

Tags: git, rebase

Let's say I have:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F  master
            \ 
             \- G - H  new feature branch
```

Now I realize that commits B and C actually 
belong to the new feature, so I want to move them to the "new feature branch". In other words, I want the "new feature branch" to start at A, and include commits B and C:

```
A - D - E - F  master
 \ 
  \- B - C - G - H  new feature branch
```

How do I do this? From what I've read, it seems that `rebase` is the feature I'm looking for, but I'd like to be sure before I mess up my repository.

(I've searched and found lots of questions and examples that are very similar, but none that are *exactly* like the scenario I've described, so I'm asking to be sure (a repo is a precious thing to ruin, after all)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix master:

```
git checkout A
git cherry-pick master~3..master # apply the changes we actually want to keep on master
git branch -f master # reposition master on new position
git checkout master
```

To drop commit D from the feature branch:

```
git checkout feature-branch~3 # or git checkout C
git cherry-pick feature-branch~2..feature-branch # apply the last 2 revisions
git branch -f feature-branch
git checkout feature-branch
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. So, just so that I understand what's going on: the "git cherry-pick" is picking commits D, E and F, right?

Comment: Exactly right. master~3 is C so it's like saying ```git cherry-pick C..master```. For cherry-pick C is where it will "start" and so the change from that revision (from B to C) revision is not "applied".

Comment: I'm actually wrong about feature branch. Feature branch has to "Drop" revision D. It should be like this:
```git checkout feature-branch~3 # or git checkout C;
git cherry-pick feature-branch~2..feature-branch # apply the last 2 revisions;
git branch -f feature-branch;
git checkout feature-branch```

Comment: So, I need to do that in the feature branch, in addition to the instructions in the master branch?

Comment: Yep. Just try up until you finish cherry-picking and then do a ```gitk master HEAD``` (assuming master is already corrected) and make sure HEAD is actually the way you want feature-branch to be (with D revision dropped).

Comment: You should be using rebase for this, less error prone (as you can see from the other answers).

Answer (score 8):

[Edmundo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531482/1256452) is right (and upvoted), but it's worth pointing out a few extra items.

First, your question talks about "moving the branch's root"—but this is Git; branches don't *have* roots, not the way you are thinking anyway.  Let's look at your graph drawing:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F  master
            \ 
             \- G - H  new feature branch
```

I think that you, like me when I first started using Git, would like to think of commits `A-B-C-D-E-F` as being on the `master` branch, and commits `G-H` as being on the feature branch.  But that's not how Git works.  Let's re-draw this, without changing any of the commit links:

```
           E--F   <-- master
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           G--H   <-- feature
```

This should make it clearer that, as far as Git is concerned, commits `A-B-C-D` are on *both* branches.  There is only one root.  That's commit `A`: it's a root because it has no parent commit, no backwards link in the chain from commit to parent.

Second, no matter how you go about this, you wind up having to *copy* some commits.  The reason is that each commit's parent ID is part of that commit's identity.  The "true name" of any commit is its hash ID, and the hash ID is built by reading the complete contents of the commit: source tree, commit message, author name and date, etc., but always including the parent ID too.<sup>1</sup>  You want your final graph to resemble:

```
  D--E--F   <-- master
 /
A
 \ 
  B--C--G--H   <-- feature
```

but the existing `D` links (or points) back to the existing `C`, not to `A`, and the existing `G` points back to the existing `D`.

This is why cherry-pick works: `git cherry-pick` essentially *copies* a commit.  The new copy "does the same thing" as the original, but has *something* different, even if it's as simple as "my parent is ...".  (Usually it also has a different attached *tree* object as well, it's just that the *change* it makes, when compared to its new parent, is the same as the change the original makes when the original is compared to the original's parent).  What this means is that [you can't actually get what you want, just what you need](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BykilS816E):

```
  D'-E'-F'  <-- master
 /
A
 \ 
  B--C--G'-H'  <-- feature
```

where the little tick mark indicates that the result is a *copy* of the original.

What happens to the originals?  The answer is: they're still there, in the repository, in case you need them.  The full picture is more like this:

```
    D'-E'-F'   <-- master
   /
  /        E--F   [abandoned]
 /        /
A--B--C--D
       \  \
        \  G--H   [abandoned]
         \
          G'-H'   <-- feature
```

While `git cherry-pick` works, what `git rebase`—especially `git rebase -i`—does is to do these copies in a fancy automated fashion, with a final step to move the branch name, abandoning the original commits.  So `git rebase -i` is sometimes an *easier* way to go about it.

If you run `git rebase -i` you see all those `pick` commands, and those literally run `git cherry-pick`: it really is doing a series of cherry-picks.  If you do these yourself, it may be clearer what is going on, and you have a lot more control over when the branch labels are moved-around.

---

<sup>1</sup>For merge commits, this is parent**s**, plural.  All parents participate in the hash.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `git rebase`.

First, let's rebase some commits from `master`:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git rebase --onto A C
```

This will move all commits in the range from C to `master` (but not including C itself) onto the commit A.

Now rebase `feature` but throw out commit D:

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase --onto C D
```

Similar to the previous command, this will move commits in the range from D to `feature` (not including D itself) onto C.