# git: how do I find the common ancestor of two branches... that have already been merged

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

In order to find the common ancestor of 2 git branches, one needs to do:

```
git merge-base branch another_branch
```

Okay. But... what if both branches have already been merged? When I use `merge-base` in that case, the commit I get is the latest one before the merge, and I would like to know the common ancestor from which both branches came out "before the merge".

In other words:

```
Z - A - B - C - D - E - F
     \          /
      G - H - I
```

`HEAD` is at F. If I do a `git merge-base` here, the commit I get is `I`, and the one I am looking for is A, or perhaps Z. Is there any git instruction to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
git merge-base C I
```

you get the commit A you want. What are C and I? They are the parent commits of your merge commit D.

Hoy do you get them?

```
git log --pretty=%P -n 1 D
```

gives you two strings. This two strings are the commit C and I you need.

If you want to do it all together you can write

```
git merge-base $(git log --pretty=%P -n 1 MERGE_COMMIT)
```

where you have to replace MERGE_COMMIT with the hash of your merge commit D

Edit:
As @poke stated it is simpler with

```
git merge-base MERGE_COMMIT^ MERGE_COMMIT^2
```

Comment: Excuse me, but do you mean `git log --pretty=%P -n 1 D`, instead of `git log --pretty=%P -n 1 A`? (Otherwise, it would look a bit circular... In order to find commit A, I need to type in first a command involving commit A...)

Comment: You can also refer to the two parents of a merge commit `D` using `D^` and `D^^`. So that shortens this to just `git merge-base D^ D^^`.

Comment: @poke, I don't thing so. D^ is one of the parents, right, but D^^ is the parent of D^, not the other parent of D

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt Sorry, you’re right. I meant `D^` and `D^2`.

Comment: Thank you @poke. I didn't know that

Answer (score 4):

I usually need to find the ancestor between the tip of my branch, `HEAD` and the remote main development branch, say `origin/dev`. Here is what I use :

```
git log --reverse --boundary --format=%h HEAD ^origin/dev | head -1
```

It essentially says:

- Take all the ancestors except the ones common with `origin/dev`
- Include the boundary (the forking point)
- Reverse the order so the forking point is the first in the list
- Log to a format where only the `SHA` appears
- Take the first one in this list

Comment: Nice one, this finds commit even in the case the two branches were merged multiple times (e.g. dev and master in typical git flow) which is exactly what I need. Thanks!